# Testing for negative numbers

Tags: php, csv, row, negative-number

I read in a csv and put it in an multi-dimensional array

Depending on an array value of one of the item I colour the row read.  This works well for positive values of less than a threshold but for negative it is not satisfying this case so for values of cxy below I have -8, -30, -24 being printed corrected but the colour the row is not edited as per condition.  Why is that?

```
$rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_GET['result_view']));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv    = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

foreach($csv as $row){

   if ( $row["cxy"] < 10 ) {
       print('<tr bgcolor="#ff0000">');
   }
   else
   {
       echo "<tr>";
   }

   foreach ($row as $cell) {
       echo "<td>" . ($cell) . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
```

Comment: I have attempted using type conversion in this case but no change in result

Comment: @CBroe Even if PHP wasn't able to typecast a numeric string into an it (which it is, btw), it would eval the string to `0`, which is still `< 10`.

Comment: What do `var_dump($row["cxy"])` and `var_dump((int)$row["cxy"])` echo for your problematic values ?

Comment: var_dump resolved the issue..  Someone had changed the csv without updating the php html render so that row["cxy"] contained similar data but another row["cxy_diff"] should have been tested under the new structure.... so 0 gave red but negative numbers in diff were sill positive and higher than threshold while I was still looking at the old row.....

Comment: When in doubt, always `var_dump` ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Cast** your `$row["cxy"]` value using the **[intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)** function

```
if ( intval($row["cxy"]) < 10 )
```

Comment: it can be comment rather than answer .

Comment: Tried intval and (int) and even (float)